# Can't locate iframe content

Tags: html, powershell, iframe

I'm using powershell to automate a local aspx web application through Internet explorer at my job. I have learned what I thought was necessary to complete these tasks. I was able to login, select from a dropdown and submit a form. I haven't added code because I feel it would take away from the real question which I feel is more of a fundamental issue.

Lastly, I reached a page where all I want to do is click this one button. I scoured the source of the page and could not find any mention of a button or a click. Very disappointing.

Then, I utilized the F12 DEVELOPER TOOLS in Internet explorer and used the 'search HTML' function for the button. Voila, I found it. The button, an input element, is many layers into this ugly HTML page. Why is this element here but not in the page source?!! Sry for my frustration.

It is inside of a `iframe` inside of a `div` if that helps. I have done everything I could find on the iframes... Such as `.contentdocument` and `.contentwindow` and eitherone `.document` but they're all blank. I see it inside the iframe HTML on my developer tool thing. Wtf. I can't find this element. Please help.

Comment: Because it has been added at run-time with JavaScript. You won't see it in page source because it reflects page source code as it has been downloaded from server.

Comment: Wow I ramble. It is inside a <iframe> inside of <div>. I have done everything I could find on the subjects to access content but still can't find it.

Comment: thank u. So can I capture an element that has been added at runtime?

Comment: If it's inside an iframe...you're just searching on wrong place. You won't find it with any getElementsByXYZ() because it'll traverse page DOM, not iframe DOM

Comment: It's not enough that you wait page itself has been loaded (`document` is ready), you have to do it for `iframe` itself. Search for it then wait for its `load` event.

Comment: I have been using powershell command line not a script yet. Would the iframe's load event already have fired?

Comment: The step before the one I am at requires me to execute $xform.submit(). I see that the element I am looking for only appears after I submit. However my $ie.document variable seems to not catch up. Again, I am using the command line operator of powershell

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a really frustrating part of the IE object model.  The iFrame is there, but it's a little difficult to get to.  Here's some sample code that manipulates an iFrame, after using my [AutoBrowse](http://autobrowse.start-automating.com) module to start up the page.

```
# Gets the active browser (at this point in the script it will be the create or edit contribution page)
$browser = Get-browser | Where-Object { $_.LocationUrl -like "http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/*" }
$b = $browser
# Search thru the iFrames within the document for the frame you want
$editorFrame = $b.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe") |
    Where-Object { $_.Src -like "*source_editor.htm" }
$aboutModule = 'stuff'
# Update the content in the inner frame
$editorFrame.contentDocument.getElementById("htmlSource").value = $aboutModule
$editorFrame.contentDocument.getElementById("insert").click()
```

Just looking at the awkwardness of iFrame manipulation makes me want to add functions to AutoBrowse to make it easier.  I may just do that.  Anyways.  That's how you can manipulate the browser object to work with an iFrame contents.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this thread, the conventional approaches to accessing iframe contents worked correctly. I was able to find the elements I needed by creating a variable `doc2 = $iframename.contentwindow.document` and so on from there. I do not fully understand why I couldn't do it earlier. I was attempting to do so through the Powershell command line instead of ISE. This worked fine as a script in the ISE. Thanks for the help guys.